# Why do 2 wired connections show in Network Connections when I only have one physical connection?

Tags: networking, 18.04

I am using Lubuntu 18.04.

Network connections shows 2 wired connections, and both have been used within the last 15 minutes, even though I am connected to Wifi. Please can you explain why, and if this is normal.

I am asking this question in the broader context of trying to find out why my Wifi keeps dropping randomly.  There are several unresolved bug reports describing this behaviour, but nobody has solved the problem. Could these wired connections have anything to do with the wifi drops ?

[Link to pastebin with some system diagnostic information](https://pastebin.com/ZLEBrMXK)

Comment: You appear to have TWO ethernet controllers, and only one is connected, and not even at 1G, so you may also have a cabling problem. What make/model computer? Is this a server? The wireless problem should be another question.

Comment: The terminal command `lspci` is designed to show all the different PCI devices you have in your computer. It has nothing whatever to do with which are or are not actually connected. It has nothing to do with dropping wifi. It is entirely normal.